# Iphone Gamekit Multiplayer game via Internet

Tags: iphone, ios, gamekit, multiplayer

Iphone Gamekit is very useful to create multiplayer games.

But I got this question. There are lots of resources and tutorials in the internet create multiplayer games for players who can join via blootooth , or wifi. But the players should be connect via same network. But is there a way to connect users from any where in the world. For example lets say in a card game i am one player, and game will search through the users all over the world and randomly connected 3 players with me to play the game. Is there any way to do it with Gamekit. If it is possible can anyone please direct me to some article about it with code samples or post some idea about how to do it. It will be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

GameKit does what you want by default:

> Game Center matchmaking provides the infrastructure needed to allow
>   players to find other players interested in playing in a match. It
>   allows players to invite specific players—almost always a friend—or to
>   simply find other players looking for a match in your game. Once those
>   players have been discovered and formed into a match, Game Center
>   makes it easy for you to implement the networking code needed for your
>   game. **Where necessary, Game Kit routes network data through Game
>   Center’s servers so that all of the match’s participants are connected
>   to each other, regardless of where they are or what kind of network
>   they are on.**

We've a [battleship game](http://skahal.com/ships-n-battles) that use Game Center as an option to multiplayer games around the world, in the same way you wish.

See more: [Game Center Programing Guide :: Matchmaking Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/MatchmakingwithGameCenter/MatchmakingwithGameCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH12-SW2)